# Image resize doesn't work in IE8 for bootstrap framework

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, resize

I have been hacking and digging the google + stackoverflow, hope to find relevant solution that relate to my problem below but could not find one:

I am using bootstrap (twitter) ver 2.0 and encountered that the image resize doesn't work on IE8 but work on other browsers.

The original code for image resize is:

```
 <img src="alpha1-stamp.png" width="70" height="70">
```

It rendered so well in browser such as Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome but not IE8 (the only version i have on another desktop but reckon it should not work on all IE version)

Please advice and desperate need to fix this IE nightmare

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Alright, finally got it sorted and found the way to hack the boostrap.css file

Just comment the following on bootstrap.css (bootstrap framework)

```
/*
img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
} */
```

Answer (score 1):

Just comment the following on bootstrap.css (bootstrap framework)

```
img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
 /* max-width: 100%;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with Internet Explorer < 8 not respecting width & height attributes of my img tags and was able to solve it removing only the `height:auto` rules of the `img` selector.
(removing max-width didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

If removing of some code from bootstrap css didn't help you can try this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763577/789012

As for me after removing of it my layout in Chrome was broken the same way as in Mozilla or IE...

Answer (score 0):

The promblem is the
`width: auto\9;
 height: auto;`
If you comment this line it works correctly on IE

Answer (score 0):

I solved it differently by hacking conditional override styles in the HTML.

I already had an IE8 workaround section below the bootstrap stylesheet, so I add resets for the problem images:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      img, img.img-responsive {
     width:auto;
     height:auto;
     max-width: none;
      }
    </style>

<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
```